# represent probability as fraction

Tags: probability

let us consider following problem:

we have $20$ light bulb,of which $2$ is defective,we  take two bulb randomly and simultaneously ,what is probability that neither of them will be defective?

i am always surprise    because i am  starting with right way as i think and  dont get  result,for example i think that  solution of this would be $1$ minus that either or both are defective,or

$1-P(A  or B)$   is this right?

where $A$  denotes that first bulb is defective and  $B$ that second is,for $A$ we have $2/20$,for second we have $1/19$,we we have

$P(A or B)=2/20+1/19-P(A and B)$

am i correct till here?  $P(A and B)=2/20*1/19=2/380$

$2/20+1/19=58/380$ ,so after i subtract ,get result $56/380$;so finally  $1-56/380=324/380$ or $162/190$,but answer is $153/190$,what is wrong?

Comment: $PB = 2/20 = 1/10$. $PB$ is the unconditional probability.

Comment: unconditional?no thay are depenndent on each other

Comment: $B$ is the event that the second item is defective.  $PB = 1/10$.  Just as the probability that the second card in a deck is the ace of spades is 1/52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "neither of them are defective" means the same thing as "the first bulb is not defective and the second one is not defective". Hence, we have:
$$ \begin{align*}
&P(\text{first not defective and second not defective}) \\
&= P(\text{first not defective})P(\text{second not defective} \mid \text{first not defective}) \\
&= \dfrac{18}{20} \cdot \dfrac{17}{19} \\
&= \dfrac{9 \cdot 17}{10 \cdot 19} \\
&= \dfrac{153}{190} \\
\end{align*} $$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{18}{20}\times\frac{17}{19}=\frac{153}{190}\approx 0.805$.

Comment: when i multiplied $18$ by $17$,i got  incorrect result,it was typo